# Synology - delete or decrease file versions to free up disk space

Tags: disk-space, synology, synology-diskstation

Synology CloudStation file versioning uses a lot of space so how can I free up some space? How can I see how much space file versioning used?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can see how much space uses CloudStation for file versioning in this way:

1. Open CloudStation server
2. Go to Settings from the left menu
3. Go to tab Others from top menu
4. Click on Calculate and wait for few minutes

In my case it was 2.5TB out of 3.5TB (!!!)

To free up that space I did the following steps:

Reduce file versions:

- Open CloudStation
- Go to Settings from the left menu
- Go to tab Sync Settings from top menu
- For every Shared folder that has versioning rapidly decrease, or turn off, Number of versions

Clear version database:

- Open CloudStation
- Go to Overview from the left menu
- Open Version Explorer
- For each folder on the left menu (or just for those folder you know that used a most of space) execute Action - Clear version database

IMPORTANT!! - It takes time to show new free space. For me it took over night.

So maybe it is enough first to reduce file versions so if there are no result then clear version database.